# Java - mapping stream variable reassignment

Tags: java, java-8, mapping, java-stream

Using this stream, I am trying to reassign the variable c inside the stream, in order to map different results each time. I attempted to use a foreach loop outside the stream, however I realized it is made futile as it does not occur within the stream.

I have commented where I am trying to do this.

```
 List<Hills> hills = readHills();
 Set<String> countys = new HashSet<>();
    for (Hills s: hills) {
        countys.add(s.getCounty());
        String[] c = new String[0];
        c[1] = s.getCounty();
        System.out.println("### County: " + c[0]);
        hills.stream()
                .filter(Hill -> !Hill.getCounty().equals(c[0]))
                .map((Hills Hill) -> Hill.getName() + " " + Hill.getHeight())
                .forEach(Hill ->{
                        System.out.println(Hill);
                        c[0] = Hill.getCounty();     // This is what I am trying to do
                        });
             }
```

Comment: Arrays start from zero index.

Comment: You have made your code even worse, now your array has zero length, but you are still trying to access the second array element, right afterwards. Though now, every access will fail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well your `filter` most probably filters out `all results`. If it would not do that, than you would see a lot of `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` in your output. The problem is here:

```
 String[] c = new String[1];
 ... some other code
 System.out.println(Hill);
 c[1] = Hill.getCounty(); // you can only access c[0] here
```

You are declaring an array of a single element (access it by `index` zero); but you try to access it by `index 1`; which does not exist.

Even if you change the code to `c[0] = Hill.getCounty()`; you would be storing *the last result only* and because you are using `forEach` (which says that order is not guaranteed), that might not even mean the last `Hill` in the list(depending if you might later in the future change that for a `parallel stream` for example).

Comment: Forget the c[0], assuming that that is correct, is there no way to reassign the value withing the steam?

Comment: @Aresouman you would be re-assigning the variable in each step - yes, but once the stream is consumed; only the last value that was in the stream would be stored in the array. Or you mean something else?

Comment: Well, since every stream element is mapped to `Hill.getName() + " " + Hill.getHeight()`, in other words, a `String`, it is impossible to call `.getCounty()` on these objects anyway; naming the variable `Hill` doesn’t help…

Comment: Well, the OP uses several successful techniques to make the code hard to read…